# How to declare a nested unordered_map where type of the value is the same of the unordered_map?

Tags: c++

I would like to know if it's possible to declare a type, `T`, that is `unordered_map<char, T>`, where the type of the value of the `unordered_map` is also `T`, to form a tree-like structure with variable number of children.

Basically, I'm thinking about something functionaljy equivalent to using the following but **without** defining a structure like `Node` below:

```
//Node of a tree
struct Node {
   char val;
   unordered_map<char, Node*> children;
};
```

Seemingly, this would require me to declare a multi-level map with unknown levels. Is this possible?

```
unordered_map<char, unordered_map<char, unordered_map<char, unordered_map<char, ...
```

Is there anything in C++ (maybe with `std::any` and `std::any_cast`) that could solve issue above similar to Java's `Map<char, Object>`, where the value type `Object` itself is also `Map<char, Object>`?

Comment: In the map you use *pointer* to `Node`, not `Node` objects themselves (which is impossible).  The types `Node` and `Node*` are different. So `unordered_map<char, Node*> children;` should be fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah that would work, I'm just wonder is it possible to declare something like I described? Is there anything like Java's Object that could come to rescue? (Map<char, Object>). Can I use unordered_map<char, std::any>?

Comment: Pointers is the right choice here, go with it. The only change I would recommend is that you use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (or possibly [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I tried and at least on MSVC it's possible to use `unordered_map<char, Node> children` (without a pointer). Why do you think it should be impossible ? I would understand it's impossible for `Node` to hold a member of type `Node` (without a pointer), but `std::unordered_map` introduces a level of indirection similar to a pointer. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @wohlstad Because `std::unordered_map` also uses the data type for other types (like the `value_type` alias), and since `Node` is an incomplete type at that point it's not possible to use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what about support for incomplete types in `std::unordered_map`? I saw it mentioned in the answer below. Could it be the reason MSVC didn't complain ?

Comment: @wohlstad `unordered_map` is not required to work correctly with incomplete types (e.g. recursively) according to the standard. It is possible to implement in a way that does work though. I would not rely on it working. Technically undefined behavior as of the current standard.

Comment: Why would you want this? A tree is either empty or some kind of root data with some kind of collection of subtrees attached to it. The root data is exposed, but which exact kind of collection you have is an implementation detail. Proper software engineering requires hiding implementation details. You only expose it through a limited interface that makes sense to your application. So making `children` a *private* data member of `Node` is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

See https://godbolt.org/z/rKaGE14qe.

It compiles with gcc 12.1, but in gcc 11.3, it will not compile. In fact, unordered_map can support incomplete types, because the initialization of unordered_map doesn't need to create a value_type object. However, it's undefined behavior as of now.

Comment: I was thinking is it possible to achieve the same goal without defining a struct like ```Node```?